# WMB Bar File Migration from v7.1 to IIB9

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

11 Am currently migrating ESQL Message flow and Bar file codes from V7.1 to IIB9. For doing this I need to convert messageflows in to subflows. Then for creating bar files in mqsicreatebar command  I chose 'deployAsSource' option. After creation of bar files I noticed that my bar files include all ESQL and subflows which were part of compilable main message flow which I have provided in mqsicreatebar. When I deployed this bar to execution group I noticed that every ESQL and subflows are also deployed. Ideally only main messageflow should have deployed on Execution Group. Is there anything or option am not choosing while this migration, please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the toolkit, open up the Bar editor.

On the 'Prepare' tab, over on the right-hand side is a list of 4 checkboxes. One of these is 'Compile and in-line resources' - check this.

In the main editor page, make sure that only msgflows are selected. Build and Save.

When you look inside the bar file, you should only have CMF files.

EDIT: OP wanted to use the cmd line for generating the bar file. Here is a command that I used:

`mqsicreatebar -data C:\Users\Adam\IBM\IIBT10\workspace -b C:\Users\Adam\cmd.bar -p Foo -o /Foo/foo1.msgflow`

The `mqsicreatebar` [command documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/an19540_.htm) might be useful for you.

I think using the `deployAsSource` option was a mistake in this case. Here's what the doc has to say about that option.

> `-deployAsSource`
>   (Optional) Include this parameter to deploy applicable resource files without compiling them.
>   When the `-deployAsSource` parameter is used, any applicable resources are added to the BAR file as source files, and are not compiled into message flow .cmf files.
>
> You cannot include both the compiled (.cmf) and source (.msgflow) versions of a message flow in a BAR file.

Comment: My apologies, I missed that bit. I've edited my answer.

Comment: My Problem here is my code was written in WMB7, when I tried creating the Bar from MQSICREATEBAR in IIB9 it asked me to convert message flows in to sub flow. When I change message flow in Sub flow and again tried the every sub flow ,ESQL was part of bar file. What I was expecting a .cmf file along with message set as deployable on Integration node but sub flows and esql are also getting deployed on Execution Group instead.

Comment: I think to do what you want you'll have to convert the `.subflow` flows back to `.msgflow` subflows. Then when you run the `mqsicreatebar` command (like I've shown above) you should get the `msgflow` subflows and ESQL compiled into a CMF.

Comment: @WENzER if that worked for you could you please accept the answer. Thank you.